# Elasticsearch mapping update for multifield

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I just want to know is there any way to remove a field from mapping in elasticsearch?

Please find the below details so that you can understand what i am exactly trying to do.

Below is the script that i have used for creating an index with name `test_index` with mappings for type name with `test_type`.

```
    curl -XPUT 'http://elasticsearch_host:9200/test_index' -d '{
        "mappings": {
        "test_type": {
         "properties":{
            "field1":{
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "field2":{
               "properties":{
                 "sub_field1":{
                     "index":"not_analyzed",
                     "type":"string"
                  }, "sub_field2":{
                     "index":"not_analyzed",
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
    }
    }
}'
```

After executing the above script i can see the created index as per the mappings specified, And also i can be able to add new fields.

Here if wanted to remove `sub_field2` from `field2` properties in the mapping, Is there any way to do it (or is there any way to overwrite the entire `field2` properties)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change a mapping once it is created other than to add new fields. [Re-indexing with zero down time](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) describes why it is not possible and methods of re-indexing without down time.